# Jar File: no main manifest attribute, in file.jar

Tags: java, jar, javac

I was building a jar file featuring one class, Main. It was based off Main.java:

```java
public class Main {
  

  public static void main(String[] args) {
   System.out.println("hello jar file:-/");
  }

  
}
```

I compiled with this command:
`javac Main.java`

Made this manifest.txt:

```
Main-Class: Main
```

And finished with:
`jar cfm myfirstjarfile.jar manifest.txt Main.class`

When I run `java -jar myfirstjarfile.jar` I get this error:
`no main manifest attribute, in myfirstjarfile.jar`

I was then told to put manifest in META-INF and call it MANIFEST.MF but I can't compile it, so what command do I use to turn this into a jar?

Anyone know why? Thank you!

Comment: the manífest file has the name `MANIFEST.MF` and must be in the META-INF foleder

Comment: Then what command should I run to compile it into a JArchive file?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/manifestindex.html

Comment: It says to do what I originally did, which doesn't work.

Comment: ```jar cvfe main.jar Main Main.class``` *Then* ```java -jar main.jar```

Comment: Question, when running `jar cvfe main.jar Main Main.class`, what does `Main` after `main.jar` for? What is `Main` referencing?

Comment: Your `jar` command is exactly right.  Your `java -jar` command is also exactly right.  How did you create manifest.txt?  Was it with Notepad in Windows, by any chance?  Notepad has a tendency to put a Byte Order Mark (BOM) character at the start of files it saves, which would mean your manifest.txt does not have a line starting with `Main-Class:` at all;  rather, it would have a line starting with `\ufeffMain-Class:`.

Comment: I made it in the Replit text editor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

`jar cvfe main.jar Main Main.class`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).